# Array Dimension with PHP and MySQL query

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I made a function:

```
function xyz( $user_id_array = NULL ){
  if ( ! $user_id_array ) {
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT(benutzer_id) FROM anstellung;");
    $user_id_array = mysqli_fetch_all($result);
  }

  print("<pre>".print_r($user_id_array,true)."</pre>");
}
```

Now my question is if I call the function like this:

```
xyz( array(6, 2, 3) );
xyz( );
```

The output looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13
        )

)
```

How is it possible to have the same dimensions of the arrays?
The mysqli_fetch_all should look like this as well:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 9
    [1] => 13
)
```

Comment: `$user_id_array = array_column($user_id_array, 0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` with a loop to construct the desired array:

```
if (!$user_id_array) {
    $user_id_array = Array();
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT(benutzer_id) FROM anstellung;");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $user_id_array[] = $row['benutzer_id'];
    }
}
```